# Scatter plot in R

Tags: r

I am teaching myself R by re-doing some assignments in my Monte Carlo class. I built a RANDU generator in R and I am tasked with for all triplets in the sequence (u_i,u_{i+1},u_{i+2}), in which 0.5 <= u_{i+1} <= 0.51, plot u_i versus u_{i+2}.

I did the following in MATLAB during the class and I get this:

[image]

Here is the code I wrote in Latex, just note that the data stored in variable u are simply uniform random numbers between 0 and 1.

[image]

Now to my issue, I get this error in R

```
Error in if (0.5 <= u[i + 1] & u[i + 1] <= 0.51) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I am not sure what the problem is here, here is my full R code:

```
n = 20002
x <- 1:n
x[1] = 1

for(i in 2:n){
  x[i] = (65539*x[i-1]) %% 2^31
}

u <- 1:n
u[1] = 1/(2^31)
for(i in 2:n){
  u[i] = x[i]/(2^31)
}


for(i in 1:length(u)){
  if(0.5 <= u[i+1] & u[i+1] <= 0.51){
    plot(u[i],u[i+2])
  }
}
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: The argument `0.5 <= u[i+1] & u[i+1] <= 0.51` looks odd. As in how can the same value `u[i+1]` be less than or equal to 0.51 and more than or equal to 0.51 at the same time?

Comment: I think the problem here is due to `NA` values. You are trying to index `u[i+1]` which will cause it to return NA for one value(when `i=length(u)`). The same case will happen when you try to plot `u[i+2]`. Try changing your indexing and see if it works..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is for your last observation in `u`. As for your `for` loop you are asking to evaluate `u[i+1]`. Try this:

```
 for(i in 1:length(u)-1){
   if(0.5 <= u[i+1] & u[i+1] <= 0.51){
     plot(u[i],u[i+2])
   }
 }
```

Comment: Error in if (0.5 <= u[i + 1] & u[i + 1] <= 0.51) { : 
  argument is of length zero